# Generate 10 random pairs conditionally

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following for loop which is supposed to generate two random integers and call grid.place(x,y). I'm trying to figure out how to generate a different pair if grid.place(x,y) returns false. The place method returns true if the provided x and y where not previously provided. Thank you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    mx = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    my = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    grid.place(mx,my); 
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to generate a new pair *only* if `grid.place()` returns false? Currently, the loop will generate a new one regardless of the return value of `grid.place()`.

Comment: Correct. Only if grid.place returns false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the perfect situation for a `do-while` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    do{
       mx = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
       my = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    }while(!grid.place(mx,my));

}
```

Another solution would be to make use of the `Collections.shuffle()` method. like so:

```
List<Integer> xPos = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> yPos = IntStream.rangeClosed(0,10).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

Collections.shuffle(xPos);
Collections.shuffle(yPos);


for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    grid.place(xPos.get(i), yPos.get(i));
```

This will give you all coords and never repeat in better complexity than the `do-while` loop

Comment: To be honest my friend, that's not a *perfect* situation!!

Comment: I merely meant that the `do-while` loop is often neglected, but it is times like these that it can be used and abused @Yahya

Comment: Suppose that we have more than 10 pairs, it may be time consuming to repeat the process until you catch the required "unique" pair.

Comment: Shuffle is the right idea, but shuffling coordinates _independently_ is not. You'll never generate two points on the same vertical or horizontal line.

Comment: Thanks CraigR8806. Worked. I forgot about do-while loop.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid duplicate, you can use a List for example :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.add(i);//fill your list
}

Random randomGenerator = new Random();
int mx = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);//generate the first value
int x = mx;//to not lost this value we store it in another variable
list.remove(mx);//remove the first value from your list, to avoid duplicate
int my = randomGenerator.nextInt(9);//generate the second value
int y = my;
grid.place(x, y);//now, you are sure that you have two different values
```

Comment: That's a sufficient approach!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more OO like approach:

Most likely the "grid" is not infinite. This means you can create a list of all possible positions in the grid:

```
class Position{
  private final int x;
  private final int y;
  public Position(int x, int y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
  }
  public getX(){return x;}
  public getY(){return y;}
}

List<Position> availablePositions = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i =0; i<MAX_X;i++)
  for(int j =0; j<MAX_Y;j++)
    availablePositions.add(new Position(i,j));
```

Then you can  retrieve a random index from that list:

```
   for (int i =0;i<10;i++){
     Position randomPosition = 
          availablePositions.remove(
                new Random().nextInt(availablePositions.size()));
     grid.place(
        randomPosition.getX(),
        randomPosition.getY());
   }
```

This way you will never get a duplicate, but the positions taken are lost for the programs current execution.

alternatively you can just shuffle the list and take the first 10 elements:

```
 Collections.shuffle(availablePositions);
 for (int i =0;i<10;i++)
    grid.place(
        availablePositions.get(i).getX(),
        availablePositions.get(i).getY());
```

This also ensures distinct positions within the loop but you keep all positions in the list for later use...

---

> My biggest problem with this solution is that it has deterministic time at the cost of O(MAX_X * MAX_Y) memory. Other solutions have O(1) time (for small values of i), though not deterministic, and O(1) memory. – gobernador

On modern computers memory is not the limiting resource (not even on cell phones...). When programming in Java, you should not optimize for memory and/or Performance unless you have *proven* you have a problem. And if you really have a *memory problem* then Java is most likely the wrong tool for the task.

But:

When we accept some more OO in the solution then we would not need separate
`Position` objects waisting memory. We could rather have *Cell* objects with a *state* we can change instead of immutable `String` objects in the grid. Working with a custom class as elements in the grid has some more advantages aside from enabling this selection mechanism, so we should have a look at it.

`Cell.java`

```
class Cell{
  private String content = " "; // empty
  public void placeHere(String newContent){
     content = newContent;
  }
}
```

---

`Grid.java`
    // ...
    Cell[][] gameField = new Cell[MAX_X][MAX_Y];
    for(int i =0; i

Then we can collect this existing cells in a separate List:

List allCells = new ArrayList<>();
   for(Cell[] row : gameField)
      allCells.addAll(Arrays.asList(row));

And select random cells to change the state:

```
Collections.shuffle(allCells);
for(int i =0; i<10; i++)
   allCells.get(i).placeHere("*");
```

Actually we don't even need to know the changed cells coordinates. And that is what OOP is about: solve your task with as less technical knowledge in your code as possible.

And wait, there is more:

How do you *reset* the game with the pure `String` array? Right, you iterate over the complete array. but the best performance optimisation hint I ever got is:

> the fastest way to do something is not to do it.

So how can we avoid the iteration over the complete Array?

With my approach we can collect the modified cells in a separate list:

```
List<Cell> modifiedCells = new ArrList<>();
Collections.shuffle(allCells);
for(int i =0; i<10; i++){
   Cell currentCell = allCells.get(i);
   currentCell.placeHere("*");
   modifiedCells.add(currentCell);
}
```

Then you have to reset **10** cell objects in that extra list instead of `MAX_X*MAX_Y` strings in an array.

Comment: _The_ correct solution! I'd only avoid getters for coordinates, and just made `.x` and `.y` public final fields.

Comment: @9000 Thanks! But the other answers are also "correct". The advantage here is a deterministic computing time. And about the *getters*: Java has the *bean* concept that employs getters (and setters). That's why I use them on my DTOs.

Comment: The problem with repeating attempts is that they can continue indefinitely (not with a PRNG, but what if the implementation of `random` uses a better source of enthropy?). Another problem is when by mistake you ask the algorithm to put more points that there are places: the repeating attempt algorithm is guaranteed to never terminate. I know about only one correct solution: generating all possible points and randomly choose some of them. If you know another approach, I'd love to learn!

Comment: My biggest problem with this solution is that it has deterministic time at the cost of `O(MAX_X * MAX_Y)` memory. Other solutions have `O(1)` time (for small values of `i`), though not deterministic, and `O(1)` memory.

Comment: @gobernador: To my mind, the repeating-attempt solutions may may have O(1) time complexity the same way as running a full cycle of a PRNG has O(1) time complexity. While not dependent on data size, they have a potentially _huge_ constant factor. Also, you can get a random subset of a list by putting it into a circular buffer and doing random skips. For a regular grid, you don't need to keep the whole list in RAM, you can easily generate the point by its index. For a complex shape, as the one described by `grid.place(...) == False`, this will not do.

Comment: @gobernador memory consumption  should not be the major concern on modern computers/cell phones. And if it is, you may think of using some other language. More arguments in the updated answer...

Answer (score 0):

The longest and most brute-force way to approach this is to check if the coordinates already have been accessed in the grid.

You would have to start with ten and work your way down to zero.

```java
int size = 10;

for (int count = size; count > 0;) {
    mx = randomGenerator.nextInt(size);
    my = randomGenerator.nextInt(size);

    if (!grid.exists(mx, my)) {
      grid.place(mx, my);
      count--;
    }
}
```

#### Example

```java
public class Grid {
    private boolean[][] self;

    public Grid(int size) {
        this.self = new boolean[size][size];
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return this.self.length;
    }

    public boolean exists(int row, int col) {
        return this.self[row][col];
    }

    public void place(int row, int col) {
        this.self[row][col] = true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();
        for (int row = 0; row < this.self.length; row++) {
            if (row > 0) {
                buff.append(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            for (int col = 0; col < this.self[0].length; col++) {
                if (col > 0) {
                    buff.append('\t');
                }
                buff.append(this.self[row][col] ? '1' : '0');
            }
        }
        return buff.toString();
    }
}
```

```java
public class GridDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int size = 10;
        Grid grid = new Grid(size);

        for (int count = size; count > 0;) {
            int mx = (int) (Math.random() * size);
            int my = (int) (Math.random() * size);

            if (!grid.exists(mx, my)) {
              grid.place(mx, my);
              count--;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(grid);
    }
}
```

#### Output

```
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1
```

The best way to solve this would be to create some type of memory map and generate permutations and randomly iterate over those values.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but your answer will not always generate **`10`** pairs!

Comment: @Yahya You're right, I forgot to move the decrement logic into the if-statement.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check that whichever pair you are passing that is not passed previously.
Using HashSet you can achieve it:

```
HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>();
int i = 0;
while(i<10) {
    mx = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    my = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    String rand = mx + "" + my;
    if(!set.add(rand)){
        grid.place(mx,my); 
        i++;
    }
}
```

So set will ensure that whatever pair you are passing, that is not passed previously.

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    while(true){
        mx = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        my = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        if(grid.place(mx,my)) break;
    }
}
```

This while loops over, until `grid#place` returns `true`, and keeps generating random values.

Comment: Your approach my friend is similar to CraigR8806 one. I believe @YCF_L is the most sufficient one.

Comment: Why not use a do-while instead of an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to keep trying generate numbers until its gonna be placed, and fill grid 10x10, basically all you want to do is to check for already placed numbers.

```
Set<Integer> placedNumbers = new HashSet<>();

while(set.size() != 100) {
    mx = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    my = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
    if(!placedNumbers.contains(mx+my) && grid.place(mx,my)) {
       placedNumbers.add(mx+my);
    } 
}
```